# How to know whether a person left your website?

Tags: php, server-push

I am building a website in PHP and i need your help. I want to know the time of the user who logged in my site. The task was to store the login time and then the logout time. The login can be stored easily. But for logout there are many ways. The one I can think about are:

1. By clicking on the logout button.
2. By Closing the browser.
3. By letting the session gets expired.
4. Certainly by disconnecting from internet due to any reason.

I solved my problem for the first three but I don't know how to solve the Fourth one. Then Searching on net I got an idea to implement it using the **SERVER PUSH MESSAGE** method. In which the server can send message to the client browser after certain interval of time. If he gets a response then it means the user is still connected otherwise user is not connected. I liked the idea but I don't know how to implement this idea because i don't have any knowledge about the push messages.

Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Q: How to know whether a person left your website?  A: Basically, you *don't*.  Unless he explicitly logs out, or until the session times out from inactivity.  Javascript kludges just aren't scalable.  IMHO...

Comment: use web sockets to identify disconnection of clients..

Comment: you can use last access time as logout time.

Comment: can you provide me with the useful links of websocket??

Comment: @RomanNewaza how can i know the last access time of user??

Comment: For every request you update LastAccessTime of the User in Database, for example.

Comment: can you give me an elaborated answer to it with an explanatory code please

Comment: @user1929236, I'm not going to teach you codding, sorry. Small hint: `$LastAccessTime = time();`

Comment: @RomanNewaza thanks i got my answer. But if I still want to use the same technique explained above??? Can you help me with that??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23875/discussion-between-roman-newaza-and-user1929236)

Comment: @RomanNewaza I am waiting for your response there......

Answer (score 0):

From Javascript you shouldcatch the event `window.onbeforeunload`

Comment: I used it already, but it doesn't work if internet connection is lost. It works on browser close event.

Comment: @Dimitris Sapikas, what if user has not closed browser tab?